# I need to get number of Pods in a Kubernetes Cluster with kubernetes python client

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, kubernetes-python-client

i have a code to get the number of Pods it give the output but it loads too many unwanted data in (ret_pod), is there a better way to do it?

```
from  kubernetes import client , config 

config.load_kube_config()
v1= client.CoreV1Api()
ret_pod = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
print(len(ret_pod.items))
```

which gives me the output of

```
kubectl get po -A -o json
```

and then finds the length. but i just want to do the output of

```
kubectl get po -A
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it? Looks fine to me....

Comment: if i have 1000 pods it will load data of all 1000 pods i only want the count of these pods @Z4-tier

Comment: There is no API for just a count. You could maybe use a field selector but overall what you have is correct. The API is kept very simple.

Comment: @coderanger, as to `field_selector`, it will only allow to filter / narrow down the result e.g. to pods, having that specific field, containing some specific value i.e. this example `ret_pod = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(field_selector='metadata.name=python-client',watch=False)` will retrieve only a pod, which name is `python-client` but it will retrieve its entire json manifest anyway. So the example shown above is probably the most effective way of performing such task.

Answer (score 4):

In kubectl way:

```
kubectl get po -A --no-headers | wc -l
```